# Playing video in Cocos3D

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, cocos3d

I have a Cocos3D project with a cube in the middle of the scene and I want to play a video
on one of the sides of the cube.
Now, I do know it's possible I just don't know where I should even start. I'd imagine it will
be played on a plain node? or not?

Could you guys please give me a hand here?

edit: Didn't mention it's an iphone project ._.

thanks

Comment: have you checked whether this is mentioned in the docs respectively class reference? What makes you *know* that this is possible?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have searched through the docs but no luck.. I need to make my sentence clear - I know it can be done on an openGL node and I have seen it working with great performance. I just dont know how it can be done on cocos3d..

Comment: what is an opengl node?

Comment: Well not a node (sorry I'm new to this whole area), it is played on an object (which looks like a `CC3PlainNode`), made in opengl...

Comment: Could someone please help me?